# How to know the bit version of SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to know the bit version of SQL server installed in Windows 8 machine.
Tool - SQL server
OS   - Windwos 8

Answer (score 2):

Use `select @@version`. It shows version number and bit (x86, x64).

For example my SQL Server 2012 X64 shows as

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5343.0 (X64)     May  4 2015 19:11:32 
>     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Developer Edition (64-bit) on
>   Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

There's also [SERVERPROPERTY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) that you can use to get different properties of a server instance.